# Ubuntu dual boot not repaired by boot-repair after installing Windows 7

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, boot-repair

I  reinstalled Windows 7 on my dual boot machine (thinkpad x220). To get back the bootmenu I followed [this page on recovering Ubuntu after installing Windows on the Ubuntu help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)

Boot-repair says *repair successful*. But I can't find the GRUB menu even after holding the <kbd>shift</kbd> key. It directly enters Windows.  Here is the [pastebin from boot-repair](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7597449/).

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this happens, if you look through the log you will see that windows removed linux so you need to reinstall linux if you still want it